# If the roots of $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ be real and different, then the roots of $(a+c)(ax^2+2bx+c)=2(ac-b^2)(x^2+1)$ will be imaginary and vice-versa .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> If the roots of $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ be real and different, then the roots of $(a+c)(ax^2+2bx+c)=2(ac-b^2)(x^2+1)$
> will be non-real complex roots and vice-versa .

**What I've tried :**

I was thinking of finding the nature of discriminant of the equation to deduce things but I'm scared of expanding so many terms .

I too thought to use the idea of $ax^2 + 2bx + c = a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ but found no use .

*Can this problem have any better intuitive solution/approach than the standard one(posted by @Martin R in a comment) ?*

Comment: @MartinR it refers to imaginary roots

Comment: So it is a lapsus clavis? If so, can you please correct it?

Comment: @AnneBauval actually it was the actual problem statement in the book but I rectified it .

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2009093/42969

Comment: I can't figure out a meaning of "vice versa" here which could make the claim true.

Comment: @Ash_Blanc Your "rectification" is wrong. Replace "[imaginary numbers]"(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number) by "non-real complex numbers". + Don't be "scared of expanding so many terms". Calculate and relate the discriminants of both quadratic equations (without cheating and looking at Martin R 's link above).

Comment: @AnneBauval oops my misunderstanding sorry for pointing 

Comment: @AnneBauval sure mam 

Answer (score 1):

We have to add an extra condition so that your statement becomes true.
Let's examine the following case to see why your statement can be false.

If $a=0$, then $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ clearly cannot have two distinct real roots, but, for example, if $b=1$ and $c=0$, then
$$
\begin{align*}
(a+c)(ax^2+2bx+c)-2(ac-b^2)(x^2+1) &= 2(x^2+1),
\end{align*}
$$
which has two non-real roots.

If we exclude this case, then your statement is true.
That is,

> Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$.
> The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ has two distinct real roots.
> 2. $a\neq 0$ and $(a+c)(ax^2+2bx+c)=2(ac-b^2)(x^2+1)$ has two non-real roots.

---

*Proof:*

Suppose $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ has two distinct real roots.
Then $a\neq 0$, or else the equation cannot have $2$ distinct roots.
Now, we can then divide both sides of $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ by $a$
and obtain
$$
x^2+\frac{2b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}=0,
$$
which also has two distinct real roots because division by $a$ does not change the roots.
Let $p=b/a$ and $q=c/a$.
Then $p^2-q>0$.
In particular, we cannot have both $p=0$ and $q=1$.
By expanding, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
&\quad \ \, (1+q)(x^2+2px+q)-2(q-p^2)(x^2+1) \\
&= (2p^2 - q + 1)x^2 + (2p(q + 1))x + 2p^2 + (q + 1)q - 2q.
\end{align*}
$$
The discriminant is
$$
\begin{align*}
&\ \ \quad 4(p^2(q + 1)^2 - (2p^2 + (q + 1)q - 2q)(2p^2 - q + 1)) \\
&= 4(-4p^4 - p^2q^2 + 6p^2q + q^3 - p^2 - 2q^2 + q) \\
&= -4(4p^2 + (q-1)^2)(p^2 - q) < 0
\end{align*}
$$
where the last inequality is true because we cannot have both $p=0$ and $q=1$.
This shows that
$$
(1+q)(x^2+2px+q)=2(q-p^2)(x^2+1)
$$
has two distinct real roots.
Multiplying by $a^2$ (which is nonzero) on both sides, we have
$$
(a+c)(ax^2+2bx+c)=2(ac-b^2)(x^2+1),
$$
which shows that this equation also has two distinct real roots because multiplying by a nonzero number does not change the roots.

For the converse, suppose $a\neq 0$ and
$$
(a+c)(ax^2+2bx+c)=2(ac-b^2)(x^2+1)
$$
has two distinct real roots.
Since $a\neq 0$, we can divide both sides by $a^2$ and obtain
$$
(1+q)(x^2+2px+q)=2(q-p^2)(x^2+1) \tag{*}
$$
which has two distinct real roots because division by a nonzero number does not change the roots.
By the previous calculation, the discriminant is
$$
-4(4p^2 + (q-1)^2)(p^2 - q),
$$
which is negative because $(*)$ has two non-real roots.
This implies that $p^2-q>0$.
Multiplying by $a^2$ (which is nonzero),
we have $b^2-ac>0$,
which shows that $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ has two distinct real roots.

Comment: What if $a ≠ 1$ ?

Comment: You can just divide by $a$ on both sides for the first equation, and divide by $a^2$ on both sides for the second equation. But I do need to explain why I can divide by $a$ in the converse though. Will update later.

Comment: @Ash_Blanc Updated and fixed some errors. Avoided notational abuse. It should be easier to understand.

Comment: I still think there can't be more intuitive solution than the standard solution posted by @Martin R in a comment

Comment: @Ash_Blanc Why did you repost the exact same question?

Comment: Plus, at the time my answer was posted, you did not specify that you want a more "intuitive" answer.

Comment: i just edited it 'cause this one seems more interesting and wanna know more intuitive approaches to it that's it